# How can i add 3 columns as 1 in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation

Hello everyone i try to add 3 columns and display it as 1 column. When i try this i get an error i use concat and i tried this.

i am using in oracle i googled for it showed concat as a answer but it doenst work

i tried this but it says

```
select CONCAT(hiredate, 'Stared', employeeName) AS test from employee;
```

ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments

i wanna see those 3 columns as 1 so it needs to show
Tesst
15-may-2010 test Jon jones

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to use `||` concatenation operator:

```
select hiredate ||' '|| 'Stared' ||' '|| employeeName
from some_table
```

Answer (score 2):

[`CONCAT`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions026.htm)  could be used with two arguments.

You could nest `CONCAT` to handle more than strings:

```
SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT(hiredate, 'Stared'), employeeName) AS test from employee;
```